# Internal microphone not listed in sound settings

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, microphone

On a fresh 12.04 installation in sound settings the internal microphone is not listed (worked upto 11.10).
Alsamixer shows that mic is "0" and muted, but after changing that it remains undetected in sound settings.

Any help? Could also be a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/990211).

Answer (score 8):

My microphone stopped working when I upgraded to 12.04 LTS.

- I installed *Pulse Audio Volume Control*. One way to do this is:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
  ```

  Then:
- Under the "Configuration" tab, selected "Analog Stereo Duplex".
- Under the "Input Device" tab, pushed the mute button (which unmutes if muted).

Now my microphone works.

Answer (score 2):

I too had been facing the same problem for quite some time. I fixed it by changing input values under gstreamer-properties. [My experience.](http://solancer.blogspot.in/2012/10/mic-not-working-in-ubuntu-1204-solved.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this workaround:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/946232/comments/32

Hope that works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem in 12.04 LTS on a Asus K70IC. I'd set my machine to record from the internal speakers prior to upgrading, and after upgrading the microphone disappeared from all audio hardware management. Setting Pulse to "Analog Stereo Duplex" fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I resolve my problem in DELL Studio 1458 ALC665 ubuntu 12.04 with the suggestion on:
[See here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/946232/comments/32) 
Enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.