# Sound Problem - No Audio Input is Shown i.e Microphone is not Visible. Neigher "Headphone" profile is available?

Tags: sound

Sound Problem - No Audio Input is Shown i.e Microphone is not Visible ,neither the "Headphone" profile is available !

I have Headphone connected and I can hear voices coming out of it !

I suspect Cadence or GLadish is responsible for this  ! Please help. I also suspect resetting all audio related settings to back to its factory state will solve this issue !! But I dont know how to do that !?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you read/tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133903/internal-microphone-not-listed-in-sound-settings)? Also you only wrote in your question that the mic input is not shown, but you didn't say whether you can record from the mic or not?

Comment: Is this an analog or USB microphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to disable HD Audio Output for Front Michrophone in BIOS.

Comment: This seems to me like a hardware specific issue. Could you please add your hardware configuration laptop model/brand, sound cards info? It will be more helpful to compare/relate similar cases.